# Java Multithreading: How can i start external Java Programs, which are executing threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, processbuilder

currently, i'm trying to write a programm, which should execute a seperate Java-program multiple times, but with different parameters. This executed Java-program calls a Thread-Class. Within this class, a connection to a (Game)Server is established. Once connected, the Threads sends a command to turn the connected player around every 10 milliseconds.  I have 2 "solutions" for this:

The easy (working) one:

```
public class GeneralAgentTest {

public static void main(String [] args){

    Thread thread = new Thread(new HexagonRunner("127.0.0.1",6000,"UnitedTestors",-30,-15));
    thread.start();
}
}
```

This is working correctly, but not actually my goal. I need to start several of this Threads (new Thread(new HexagonRunner("127.0.0.1",6000,"UnitedTestors",-30,-15)); ) and each of this threads must be handled by a seperate process.

To do this, i wrote some code with an ProcessBuilder. This is within one class.

Second not correctly working one:

```
public void execute(Class class1, int a, String str, String team, String x,
        String y) {

    ProcessBuilder builder;
    String javaHome = System.getProperty("java.home");
    String javaBin = javaHome + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator
            + "java";
    String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
    String className = class1.getCanonicalName();

    builder = new ProcessBuilder(javaBin, "-cp", classpath,
            className, ip, port, team, str, x, y);

    try {
        process[a] = builder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("failed");
    }

public void loadPlayers() {
    process = new Process[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        try {
            execute(processes.StartProcesses.class, i,
                    playerCombo[i].getSelectedItem().toString(),
                    playerTeam[i].getText(), playerStartX[i].getText(),
                    playerStartY[i].getText());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create processes for players");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

These are the functions i wrote, to execute the class(es) who is/are starting the thread(s).
Following class is executed:

```
public class StartProcesses{

public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t = null;
        t = new Thread(new HexagonRunner("127.0.0.1",6000,"UnitedTestors",-30,-15));
        t.start();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "should've started");
}
}
```

In my second try, the parameters which are given to the StartProcesses Class are containing some information like IP-Adresses, Portnumbers, Playerpositons and stuff like this. Anyway i was trying to execute the class with "hard" information, just to be sure it is working like in my first codepart.

The connections to the server are correctly established in both attempts, but in the first one the thread keeps working. In my second try it seems like the thread is dead after the connection is established. The process is still alive, since the connection to the server is still there.

This is a bit of code, but what i want to tell, is that the Thread is working correctly when executed manually, but it is not working correctly if i try to start the class automatically with the use of ProcessBuilders.

I really really hope you guys could understand what i am trying to say. Hopefully someone has a working solution for me.

Cheers.

EDIT: Add Code for HexagonRunner:

```
public class HexagonRunner extends GeneralAgent {

// Bunch of Methods
// Important Method:

    @Override
protected void simulationCycle() {

    turnAgent(40);


}
}
```

The simulationCycle() method, is the method that is going to be go through over and over again. 
Since the class HexagonRunner is inherited from the class GeneralAgent, i'm going to post the relevant stuff of this class here as well:

```
public class GeneralAgent implements Runnable, UdpListener{

// Attributes, getters, setters, methods..

 @Override
 public final void run() {
    // giving the worker threads the signal to start
    mServerConnection.start();
    mParser.start();

    // waiting for the first information to be parsed, so that the
    // simulation loop can run
    try{
        System.out.println("GeneralAgent-Run: waiting for latch");
        mLogger.info("Run method: waiting for CountDownLatch");
        mFirstDone.await();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println("GeneralAgent-Run: InterruptedException");
        mLogger.info("Run method error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    mLogger.info("Run method: CountDownLatch now 0, continue");
    // setting the initial position
    moveToPostion(mXStartCoord, mYStartCoord);

    // the simulation loop

    while (true){
        simulationCycle();

        // Shutdown if the game is over
        if (mGameworld.getTime() >= 6000){ // later 6000+
            System.out.println("Yeah, 50 runs completed -> Shutdown");
            mLogger.info("General Agent - Time > 50, programm should terminate");
            shutdown();
            break;
        }
        // waiting for the threads to signal that they are
        // ready (e.g. have new server information)
        // for another round of the simulation loop
        mPhaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
    }
}
```

I hope things get clearer now. I still have no idea where my code fails.

Comment: “but it is not working correctly” is not a proper problem description. Explain what happens, if something unintended happens, or what doesn’t while it should; if there are error messages or exceptions, include them in your question.

Comment: Oh, i forgot this part. It's not working properly means, that it seems like the mechanism of the Threads are only executed once. I implemented a call of a JOptionPane in my HexagonRunner Thread. The JOptionPane only opens once, if i start the thread out of the created process. If i execute the class with the thread manually the JOptionPane appears requlary.

Comment: Well, it’s hard to solve that problem without seeing the actual code dealing with that `JOptionPane`. But as a general remark, Swing features shouldn’t be accessed by a background thread. See [“Swing’s Threading Policy”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading). If you don’t obey that, the results might be unpredictable.

Comment: It's just JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"whatever"); i just use this for getting a fast output from the executed class. This should actually pop-up a message-window as soon as i click away the  previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You could build somethin a lot simpler by using Executors. It' part of the comcurrent package introduced in Java 1.5. It basically works as follows:

```
// create a pool with 10 threads
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
//loop as long as you need to detach your threads
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // this actually contains the thread bit, will be executed in parallel
    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // this is where your code is
            new HexagonRunner("127.0.0.1",6000,"UnitedTestors",-30,-15)
        }
    });
}
// clean up when you're done to prevent leaks
executorService.shutdown();
```

That's it, much simple and you don't need to spawn different JVMs through ProcessBuilder, which is a lot slower.

Comment: This looks pretty good, but does not contain one of my main-goals. The HexagonRunners MUST run in seperate processes. These HexagonRunners are actually some kind of footballplayers with some kind of artificial intelligence. One of the Rules of the server is, that each player must work in its on process. The reason behind this, is that the players may not communicate in a way different than over the server-functionalities.

Comment: Well, that's ok, you can still embed your ProcessBuilder thing with you the run() Method of Runnable(). Using the executor separates the problem of spawning multiple threads from actually executing a command line call.

Comment: Either i don't understand you, or you don't understand me. I try to explain it a bit different. Each HexagonRunner must be started seperated from the others. That means, that every HexagonRunner must have its own Process on the computer (JVM). I can't simply start a bunch of these HexagonRunners out of one class.

Comment: Hi, I do understand what you mean - let me explain what happens with my proposed approach: 1) You start with one JVM process which contains the executor. The executor spawns as many runnables as you need, let say 10. Each one of these Runnable instances use ProcessBuilder to execute HexagonRunner. 2) Each  ProcessBuilder instance detaches a SEPARATE JVM through a command line call (that's what ProcessBuilder is meant for). The result is that you use ExecutorService to detach multiple threads, whose sole purpose is to detach an individual process in a separate JVM.

Comment: Alright. I just tried this and i'm still getting the same result as before. I used the ExecutorService to call my function, which is createing the processes via process builder, 4 times. My 4 HexagonRunners connect properly but they're still doesn't working any further after one run-through. The processes are remaining alive and my HexagonRunners keep beeing connected, but they stop going through their mechanisms.

Comment: can you post the code of the HexagonRunner? that bit of code needs to run - as mentionied before, the run time behaviour of HexagonRunner is not influenced by the Executor.

Comment: One more thing: if you want your HexagonRunner to continuously run, you'll have to implement a loop structure such as while(condition) { .... }